# ¿Cómo reacomodar las filas en columnas similar a PIVOT de SQL?

Tags: mysql, python

Tengo la siguiente tabla que la he organizado con sentencia SQL y la he acomodado en una Qtablewidget:

```
ID  PRODUCTO TALLA  UNIDS
01  polo       S     5
02  polo       M     10
03  pantalon   S     2
04  pantalon   L     7
05  pantalon   XL    8
```

Pero como podria hacer para organizarla de la siguiente manera:

```
 PRODUCTO  S  M  L  XL
 polo      5  10
 pantalon  2     7  8
```

ACTUALIZACION
He utilizado PANDAS y con el siguiente codigo lo he logrado:

```
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='rincon', db='texpal')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT idarticulo,idtalla,cantidad FROM detalle_pedido')
    table_rows = cur.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
    dff=pd.pivot_table(df,index=[0], values=[2],columns=[1], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

He visualizado los valores con PRINT pero nohe logrado insertarlos con éxito en una Qtablewidget.¿Como se haría?

Comment: Realizar este tipo de operaciones es bastante trivial con pandas, pero al querer evitarlo es necesario que indiques en qué formato está tu dataset. Estamos hablando de una lista de diccionarios?

Answer (score 1):

como dice @Cesar con pandas es relativamente fácil modificar esa tabla, por eso te pongo una opción de hacerlo. Yo lo que haría sería recoger los datos en un df, y una vez los tenga. Crear las columnas que necesitas y asignarlas el valor 0 por defecto, en este caso:

```
df = pd.read_excel("datos.xlsx", index_col=False)
df["S"] = 0
df["M"] = 0
df["L"] = 0
df["XL"] = 0
```

Después crearía un método que recorra todas las filas y así asignar el nuevo valor según sea el tamaño.

```
def new_data(x):

    if x.talla == "S":
        x["S"] = x["unidades"]
    if x.talla == "M":
        x["M"] = x["unidades"]
    if x.talla == "L":
        x["L"] = x["unidades"]
    if x.talla == "XL":
        x["XL"] = x["unidades"]
    return x
```

Una vez ya tengas el método he usado apply de pandas para recorrerlo, el parámetro axis, debe ser 1 si quieres que sea las filas y 0 si quieres usar el método en la columna.
Una vez lo tengas asignado a un dataframe, eliminar las columnas que no quieres que salgan. Y por ultimo hacer un groupby de los productos:

```
df_new = df.apply(lambda x: new_data(x), axis=1)
df_new.drop(columns=["id", "unidades"], inplace=True)
final_df = df_new.groupby("producto", as_index=False).sum()
```

Te recomiendo que te leas la documentación de [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) y así poder tener más soluciones. Un saludo.

Comment: Otra opción sería utilizar el método `pivot` de pandas: `df.pivot(index='producto', columns='talla', values='unids')`

Comment: @CésarGonzález Gracias. He utilizado PANDAS y he logrado visulizarlo con PRINT pero no he logrado insertarlo en una Qtablewidget. El procedimiento que utilizaba antes ya no me resulta con esta tabla Pandas. ¿Como se haría?

Comment: Personalmente lo haría con la librería [pandasqt](https://github.com/draperjames/qtpandas) o bien escribiendo un modelo con el dataframe como fuente de datos